# Open a image file then display it in new window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a button in my GUI then after selecting a image file I want it to display in new window.

**Code:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *   
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageTk  # Place this at the end (to avoid any conflicts/errors)

window = tk.Tk()
a = Tk()

def openimgfile():
    currdir = os.getcwd()
    name = filedialog.askopenfile(initialdir = currdir, title = "Select a Image", filetype = ( ("PNG", "*.png"), ("JPEG", "*.jpg;.*jpeg"), ("All files", "*.*") ) )                         

a.title("Pattern Matching")
a.minsize(200,200)
button1 = Button(text="Open file",width = 10,height =10,command=openimgfile).pack()

a.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the use for `window = tk.Tk()` and then create another instance of Tk?

Answer (score 1):

For this to work you need to initialize this in command function:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os

window = Tk()


def open_img_file():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=os.getcwd(
    ), title="Select file", filetypes=(("png images", ".png"), ("all files", "*.*")))
    if not filename:
        return
    # setup new window
    new_window = Toplevel(window)
    # get image
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(filename))
    # load image
    panel = Label(new_window, image=image)
    panel.image = image
    panel.pack()


window.title("Pattern Matching")
window.minsize(200, 200)
button = Button(text="Open file", width=10, height=10,
                command=open_img_file)
button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Nice explanation sir and it works :) Happy coding :D

Answer (score 1):

### Use this to display the image in `tkinter`:

Display image :)

> ```
>  from tkinter import *
>
>  def makeLabel(parent, image):
>      # Make label to display the image
>      label = Label(parent, image=image)
>      label.pack()
>
>  def showImg():
>      # Define root window!
>      root = Tk()
>
>      # Bring the image to the script!
>      img = PhotoImage(file='YOUR_PIC.png')
>
>      # Show image as label
>      makeLabel(root, img)
>
>      # Update root (GUI)
>      root.mainloop()
>
>  if __name__ == '__main__':
>      showImg()
> ```

### *Also you can using matplotlib :)*

### Use library

It's cool  ^_^

You can display an image very simply by using `matplotlib`:

> ```
> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
> import matplotlib.image as mpimg
>
> img = mpimg.imread('YOUR_PIC.png')
> imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
>
> plt.show()
> ```

### Install library

But install it before using it :)

> **python2:**
>
> > ```
> >     pip2 install matplotlib
> > ```
>
> **python3:**
>
> > ```
> >     pip3 install matplotlib
> > ```